# How much energy is required to operate a Sabatier reactor?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, energy, chemical-engineering, ideal-gas

I am trying to model some industrial processes and having a hard time finding information about the [Sabatier reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction). The Sabatier reaction combines $\ce{CO2}$ (and possibly $\ce{CO}$) with $\ce{H2}$ to produce $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CH4}$.

On the one hand, this reaction is exothermic. On the other hand, it requires high heat and pressure. Does the reactor need initial heating and pressurizing of the gases, and then is it self-sustaining (or rather requiring cooling)?

What is clear is that some energy is be needed to compress gases and flow them over the catalysts.

Are there any estimates of how much energy a reactor would use? I understand that scale would also be an important parameter, but any preliminary estimates are useful to me.

Comment: It is a chemical kinetics issue.  Raising the temperature increases the rate of the reaction.

Comment: Useful paper on this topic regarding the need to initially heat and then remove heat from reactor. https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2018/se/c8se00073e#!divAbstract

Comment: It is rather chemical engineering question, comparing rate of heat production and rate of heat sink at given operational temperature.

Comment: I'm a chemical engineer. What is the heat of reaction for this reaction? I mean the place I work at is doing an even stupider reaction so this one deserves a bit more looking into

Comment: @Maurice your answer has zero value. Do you know what "modeling" means. Maybe you should climb down from your high horse so you can read the question better?

Comment: @dlight. Please explain ! I have not written anything about this question.

Comment: @Maurice I guess your comment was deleted by admins yesterday, although it should have been deleted the same day you posted it.